# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal with whitespace only

Tags: javascript, php

I try to launch parameters from javascript function, but it seems to be a problem with quote when I've a white space.

This is the error of Mozilla

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

And this is my code

```
$requete = pg_query($dbconnect,"SELECT '<table id=''id1''><col width=''30%''/><col width=''20%''/><col width=''30%''/><col width=''20%''/><tr></tr><tr><td id=''fiche'' colspan=4>Caract</td></tr><tr><td>Stat</td><td>'||coalesce(stat,'')||'</td><td>Service1</td><td>'||coalesce(serv,'')||'</td></tr><tr><td>Date1</td><td>'||coalesce((substring(CAST(date1 AS character varying) from 9 for 2)||'/'||substring(CAST(date1 AS character varying) from 6 for 2)||'/'||substring(CAST(date1 AS character varying) from 1 for 4)),'')||'</td><td>Heure fin</td><td>'||coalesce(heure_fin,'')||'</td></tr><tr><td>Heure début</td><td>'||coalesce(heure_debut,'')||'</td><td>Durée</td><td>'||coalesce(duree::varchar,'')||'</td></tr><tr><td colspan=2><a onclick=document.getElementById(''affichage_popup'').style.display=''none''; class=''bouton'' id=''retour''>Retour</a></td><td colspan=2><a onclick=lancement(''script\\\php\\\postgres_query.php'',0,''DELETE FROM table WHERE id=2''); class=''bouton'' id=''supprimer''>Supprimer la fiche</a></td></tr></table>' AS fiche FROM table")
```

If I analyze the code return with Mozilla I've this

```
<a id="test')" where="" intervention="" from="" onclick="lancement('script/php/postgres_query.php',0,'DELETE" id="supprimer" class="bouton">Supprimer la fiche</a>
```

I tried to replace whitespace with regular expression like '/s' bu it's the same thing.

Comment: Seems the error is here `onclick="lancement('script/php/postgres_query.php',0,'DELETE"` , there is no closing `)` Also why there is two id on same anchor tag

Comment: If I write `onclick=lancement(''script\\\php\\\postgres_query.php'',0,''DELETEFROMtableWHEREid=2'');`, the code return with Mozilla is good : `onclick="lancement('script/php/postgres_query.php',0,''DELETEFROMtableWHEREid=2"` also, I've on Id and one class in balise `<a>`

Comment: Also, worth noting that code is EXTREMELY vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: Yes I know but it's an internal tool ;-)

Comment: I don't think that's a good excuse but I was just pointing it out. Anyway in PHP you are doing `onclick=lancement(...)` but if you have an attribute value with spaces in it, then you need to wrap the entire thing in quotes, so you need to generate `onclick="lancement(...)"` (or the equivalent in single quotes). What the browser shows you is the most likely representation it has for the node, not the actual  HTML. Badly formatted HTML can still produce _a_ node (browsers have a high tolerance for wrong input) but it doesn't mean it's going to work.

Comment: @vlaz Okay, but If I've that `<a id="test')" where="" intervention=""  from="" postgres_query.php'',0,''delete=""  php="" 'script="" onclick="lancement(">Supprimer la fiche</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you did not use pg_escape_string? http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php

```
$requete = pg_query($dbconnect,"SELECT '".pg_escape_string("<table ... </table>")."' AS fiche FROM table");
```

But if I see correct... are you kidding of that you use in HTML SQL statements... so everybody can change your statment and hack your DB ... Did you heard something about [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: unfortunately, with this function it's more easy to write the code and for that thank you very much ! But it's not the solution :-( it the same thing, but fact before to click on the button I've this code `<a onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('affichage_popup').innerHTML = '&lt;table (...) onclick=lancement(script/php/postgres_query.php,0,DELETE FROM table WHERE id=2)&gt;Supprimer la fiche&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;';document.getElementById('affichage_popup').style.display='block';" href="#">36970</a>` and when I click that explode...

Comment: Finally and with your help, I choosen to use variables and not use SQL injection. It's more safety and it's finallly more easy ! Thank you for your help